# Add dependency on gradle plugin tasks

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to add a dependency task to a task which is part of gradle plugin. The plugin is `ya-cf-app-gradle-plugin` and version is `2.1.0`. This is a plugin to push the app to Pivotal Cloud Foundry by setting the appropriate configuration inside `cfConfig`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.13.RELEASE'
        cfAppVersion = '2.1.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("com.github.pivotalservices:ya-cf-app-gradle-plugin:${cfAppVersion}")
    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve to run the predefined `clean` and `build` task before executing `cf-app` plugin. Right now I am running the cf-push as `./gradlew cf-push --no-daemon`

Comment: It should be something like: `tasks['cf-push'].dependsOn clean, build`. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks for more information.

Comment: Thanks. It worked:)